# Why some of DLLs using ordinal numbers as function name rather than define textual name?

Tags: windows, dll, dllimport, dllexport

Some of DLLs e.g. `c:\windows\system32\mfc42.dll` has a long list of ordinal numbers. According to [What is an Ordinal number?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vishalsi/2007/02/26/what-is-an-ordinal-number/), ordinal numbers are exported functions and can be use as the name of function when calling.

My questions are:

- Is there any reason to use ordinal numbers as the name of function rather than define more understandable textual name?
- Is there any way to get more description of function from ordinal numbers?

Comment: It is a micro-optimization.  Well, this was 20 years ago so it probably still mattered a little.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason to use ordinal numbers as the name of function rather than define more understandable textual name?

It is quicker to bind to a function exported by ordinal that by name. However, it is very rare in real world scenarios for this performance difference to have measurable impact.

> Is there any way to get more description of function from ordinal numbers?

In general, no there is not, unless the library offers extra bespoke functionality to do so.

Comment: @pe3z: David is referring to [import binding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100318-00/?p=14563) and [import hinting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100317-00/?p=14573).